# Proper way to use Scanner with multiple methods in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a console application with a `main` method and some methods that I call from `main`. There, I want to ask the user for some input, for which I use the `Scanner` class.

Here's my problem:

I find there is no way to use `Scanner` when reading inputs from outside `main` without random exceptions or unexpected behaviour. I have tried two approaches:

1. Having a `Scanner` global variable in the class containing `main`. Then
   I use this same `Scanner` in all functions in that same class.
2. In every function I need to ask for input, I declare a new `Scanner`
   variable, use it, and `close` it before exiting the function.

1. makes `Scanner` try to read twice. I mean, I have a `sc.readLine` in a function and when I exit that function I have another `sc.readLine` in `main`. I input once and the two `readLine` lines get executed, the second one reading an empty `String`.

2. throws `Exception` (*base class Exception*) when I call any `sc.readLine` for a second time during the execution of the program.

I have also noticed that any other method other than `readLine` is going to read various items on the same line. For example, line `"10 20 30 40"` would execute 4 `sc.nextInt` calls.

**TL;DR:** how do you use `Scanner` in a console application?

Comment: Java doesn't support the concept of global variables. basically,you're just looking about how to provide input by console?

Comment: Use way 2. If you use it correctly and there is valid input to read, there won’t be an exception.

Comment: I'm using number 2 and I'm getting a NoSuchElementException. I can provide some basic code if you want

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph 2 would not work if you close the `Scanner`, as he specifically mentions asking for user input, meaning he is using `System.in` to open the `Scanner`.  If you close the `Scanner` that is on `System.in` you will be unable to open `System.in` again and the code will fail when you try to create and use another `Scanner`.  You will have to _not_ close the `Scanner` irregardless of the warning if it uses `System.in`.

Comment: "I declare a new Scanner variable, use it, and close it before exiting function" closing Scanner will also close resource from which it reads its data, so if you have function like `void foo(){Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); /*do some stuff with scanner*/ sc.close()}` then after `foo` will be called first time it will close `System.in` which will prevent you from reading from it again (like when you would like to use `foo()` again). Instead create one scanner and *pass it as parameter* like `void foo(Scanner sc){/*use scanner*/}` and use it with already existing scanner like `foo(scan);`.

Comment: @Pshemo You don't need to pass it as a parameter, depending on the functionality it is completely valid to open the `Scanner` from within the method, you just need to not close it if it uses `System.in`.

Comment: Ok, so not closing Scanner when using 2 or declaring Scanner in Main and passing it as parameter. Thank you very much. You can provide the answer so I accept it if you want

Comment: @Nexevis I mean, yeah, obviously don’t `close` a scanner attached to the standard input stream.

Comment: @Nexevis Well you are right, we don't *need* to pass it as parameter, but creating new Scanner each time method is called feels like wasting resource (memory and time). Passing already existing scanner as parameter feels more natural to me. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Beware of another problem with having multiple Scanners which handle same resource which is: they read entire (or some big chunk - need to check) data available in resource and cache it. For instance when we have `int getNumber(){return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();}` and we ask user to provide N numbers like `print("give me 4 numbers);for (/*N times/*){ list.add(getNumber()); }` but user will provide input in form `1 2 3 4(enter)` then Scanner from first call of `getNumber()` will consume all available data leaving nothing for other scanners created in next calls of `getNumber()`.

Comment: @Pshemo Actually I double-checked the implementation, and hence removed my comment: the `Scanner` class is *horrifically* wasteful. It *should* be cheap to construct, but it simply isn’t. Your instinct was right. Most of this is a quality-of-implementation issue: it could be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use a single instance of Scanner (or any other datatype or class), you can use the design pattern "Singleton" which consist to instantiate a single instance of your Object for the whole project.

The Singleton definition (a new class) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerSingleton {
    private static Scanner sc = null;

    private ScannerSingleton() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    public static Scanner getInstance() {
        if (sc == null) {
            synchronized(ScannerSingleton.class) {
                if (sc == null)
                    sc = new ScannerSingleton();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and each time you want to use your scanner anywhere you only have to call `ScannerSingleton.getInstance()` which will return your single instance of scanner

example of use:

```
String test = ScannerSingleton.getInstance().nextLine();
```

Comment: Beware that your “singleton” isn’t thread safe, and it feels conceptually iffy (besides the general problems with singletons): you *don’t* want a single scanner. You want a single *standard input scanner*. Yes, that’s what your code does, but the class name reflects this poorly.

Comment: how it isn't safe?

Comment: If two threads call `getInstance` simultaneously, `sc` potentially gets initialised twice, and you’ve therefore created two `ScannerSingleton`s, and two `Scanner`s over `System.in`.

Comment: I understand, after editing my answer, you won't have this problem which statistically, its risk is low, since it can only happen when the Singleton is called for the first time.

Comment: A Microsoft engineer famously noted that “‘one in a million’ is next Tuesday”. Meaning, when code is run frequently, even occurrences with a *very* small chance are statistically guaranteed to occur in the long run. **Never** trust low chances (unless you can exactly quantify them, as in the case of GUID collisions, which are indeed so rare that they will *never* happen).

Comment: that's right, I assume that now we have no risk, I mean after the edit of the answer, no? since the risk can happens only on the first call, we synchronize after testing if it is null(only on the first call will be null), so that we don't synchronize on each call.

Comment: Your initial edit fixed the problem (though it made calling it expensive). But your second edit *reintroduced the problem!* You need to employ double-checked synchronisation; in other words, inside your `synchronized` block you need to perform the null check *again*.

Comment: I re-edit it to avoid the coast of the synchronization at each time. we don't need to null check again, since the risk may happens only on the first call. So only at the first call all the threads will find it null, so at this time we synchronize. but in later calls we won't have any problem, since it will never be null

Comment: well well, you're right, I have to double check .. thanks for this interesting discussion

Answer (score 1):

**One way:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Scanner getScanner() {
        return scanner;
    }

    void fun1() {
        Scanner in = getScanner();
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        System.out.println("You entered: " + in.nextLine());
    }

    void fun2() {
        Scanner in = getScanner();
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(n + " + 10 = " + (n + 10));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.fun1();
        m.fun2();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a string: Hello world!
You entered: Hello world!
Enter an integer: 25
25 + 10 = 35
```

**Another way:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static void fun1(Scanner in) {
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        System.out.println("You entered: " + in.nextLine());
    }

    static void fun2(Scanner in) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(n + " + 10 = " + (n + 10));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        fun1(in);
        fun2(in);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a string: Hello world!
You entered: Hello world!
Enter an integer: 25
25 + 10 = 35
```

**Regarding your problem with `next()` or `nextInt()`:** Given below is the recommended way for multiple inputs in one go.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = true;
        System.out.print("Enter some intgers: ");
        String strNum = in.nextLine();
        String[] strNumArr = strNum.split("\\s+");
        int[] numArr = new int[strNumArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strNumArr.length; i++) {
            try {
                numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNumArr[i]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                numArr[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numArr));
        if (!valid) {
            System.out.println("Note: invalid inputs have been reset to " + Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter some intgers: 10 5 20 15
[10, 5, 20, 15]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter some intgers: 4     40 a    20   b   15
[4, 40, -2147483648, 20, -2147483648, 15]
Note: invalid inputs have been reset to -2147483648
```

Check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for more information about console input using `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to pass your `Scanner` object as another parameter for your functions.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
  String answer = ask(scanner, "what is your name?");
  System.out.println("Oh! Hello dear " + answer + "!");
  scanner.close();
}

private static String ask(Scanner scanner, String question)
{
  System.out.println(question);
  return scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: before, import java.util.Scanner.